# Не подгружается карта на IOS устройствах

Tags: ios, yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

На смартфонах iphone не грузится карта. Вместо нее серый фон блока, в котором должна инициироваться карта. Блок 100% ширины и 400px высоты. В чем может быть проблема не понимаю.
Сайт http://nada4u.ru/u-reki

Устройства:
iphone 13pro, версия 16.1.1, сафари.
iphone Xr, версия 16.2, хром 113.0.5672.69

Comment: А поддержка Яндекс ничего не сказала? Это скорее к ним вопрос.

Comment: Не спрашивал еще. Может у кого была подобная ситуация и как она решилась.